# Cannot copy DB cross server ("Log in failed")

Tags: azure-sql-database

Hi I'm trying to copy SQL instance from east us to west Europe and I'm getting the next error:

> Msg 40532, Level 11, State 1, Line 1
>
> Cannot open server "eastusserver" requested by the login.  The login failed.

I'm using this query:

> CREATE DATABASE NewDBName
>      AS COPY OF [eastusserver].OldDBName

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't copy databases between servers in separate data centers and sub-regions in Azure SQL Database ([docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff951624)).  Look instead into using [bacpacs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh335292.aspx), [scripts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee621790.aspx) or [SQL Data Sync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh456371.aspx) .